# How to make a list/matrix out of an expression?

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to make a matrix out out of the following expression:

$$
(\Omega^2 (2 d\theta^2 + d\phi^2 - 
    d\phi^2 \cos(2 \theta) \coth(\chi)^2) + (2 d\Omega^2 + (2 d\theta^2 + d\phi^2 - 2 d\chi^2) \Omega^2) \textrm{csch}(\chi)^2)/(2 \Omega^2)
$$

so that I get for the 11-components all terms that belong to $d\Omega^2$, for the 22-component all the terms belonging to $d\chi^2$, etc. (As there are no 'cross-terms', the matrix in this case should be diagonal). How do I go about this in *Mathematica*?

---

Code for copying:

```
(Ω^2 (2 dθ^2 + dϕ^2 - dϕ^2 Cos[2 θ] Coth[χ]^2) +
 (2 dΩ^2 + (2 dθ^2 + dϕ^2 - 2 dχ^2) Ω^2) Csch[χ]^2)/(2 Ω^2)
```

Comment: Please include the expression in *Mathematica* code for easy manipulation.  Thanks

Comment: Of course, here you go: (\[CapitalOmega]^2 (2 d\[Theta]^2 + d\[Phi]^2 - 
    d\[Phi]^2 Cos[
      2 \[Theta]] Coth[\[Chi]]^2) + (2 d\[CapitalOmega]^2 + (2 d\
\[Theta]^2 + d\[Phi]^2 - 
       2 d\[Chi]^2) \[CapitalOmega]^2) Csch[\[Chi]]^2)/(2 \
\[CapitalOmega]^2)

Comment: You can edit your question to add such information.

Answer (score 2):

With the expression and the variables defined

```
expression =   1/(2 Ω^2) (Ω^2 (2 dθ^2 + dϕ^2 - dϕ^2 Cos[2 θ] Coth[χ]^2) +
              (2 dΩ^2 + (2 dθ^2 + dϕ^2 - 2 dχ^2) Ω^2) Csch[χ]^2);

differentials = {dχ, dθ, dϕ, dΩ};
```

You can get what you asked by calling

```
CoefficientArrays[expression, differentials][[3]] // Normal // MatrixForm
```